# Yii2 model search query to get shop open in monday & friday

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

I want write Yii2 model search query to get shop open in monday & friday.

below are table structure and query

```
shop_name  openday 
------------------------
    shop-A      Monday  
    shop-A      Tuesday
    shop-A      Wednesday
    shop-A      Thursday
    shop-A      Friday
    shop-B      Monday 
    shop-B      Tuesday


SELECT shop_name
FROM availability   WHERE openday IN ('Monday', 'Friday')
GROUP BY shop_name HAVING COUNT(*) = 2;
```

i want to impliment this query yii2 model search,

```
$query->andWhere("(`parking_availability`.`day` IN('Monday', 'Friday'))")->groupBy('parking_availability.day')->having('COUNT(*) = 2');
```

above query not working 
Please help me...

Comment: Not working in what way? Are you getting any errors back?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$query->andWhere(['in', 'day', ['Monday', 'Friday']])
    ->groupBy('openday')
    ->having('COUNT(shop_name) = 2');
```